# How to count time difference and sum between times specialized in a sqlsrv_fetch_array

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to create an online worksheet, but I don't know how to set up a dynamic array in sqlsrv_fetch_array to do that

```
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql4 );
if( $stmt3 === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while( $row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
    echo $row3[0].": ".$row3[1]."<br />";
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt3);
$frtm=strtotime('18:56:18');
$sntm=strtotime('13:40:54');
$trtm=strtotime('11:24:40');
$fttm=strtotime('10:45:03');
echo "Total work: ".gmdate("H:i:s", ($frtm-$sntm)+($trtm-$fttm));
```

I get the result of the sqlsrv_fetch_array which I put staticaly under it just for a check. I would like to place these results to the array and make it count the actual working hours.

Comment: What is the SQL statement stored in `$sql4`?

Comment: $sql4 = "select convert(varchar(20), dbo.TEVENT.EVN_DATE, 108) AS TIMEPART, dbo.TEVENT.EVN_DIRECTIONTEXT
  from dbo.TEVENT
  inner join TPERSON on dbo.TEVENT.PRS_ID=TPERSON.PRS_ID
  WHERE dbo.TEVENT.PRS_ID IS NOT NULL AND dbo.TEVENT.DEV_ID IS NOT NULL AND dbo.TEVENT.EVN_DIRECTIONTEXT IS NOT NULL 
  AND DEV_ID = '1130' AND PRS_NAME = '$selected_val' AND convert(varchar(20), dbo.TEVENT.EVN_DATE, 101) = '$selected_val2'
  ORDER BY TIMEPART ASC";